# Python: Selecting longest consecutive series of dates in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, series

I have a series of lists (np.arrays, actually), of which the elements are dates.

```
id
0a0fe3ed-d788-4427-8820-8b7b696a6033    [2019-01-30, 2019-01-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-02-0...
0a48d1e8-ead2-404a-a5a2-6b05371200b1    [2019-01-30, 2019-01-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-02-0...
0a9edba1-14e3-466a-8d0c-f8a8170cefc8    [2019-01-29, 2019-01-30, 2019-01-31, 2019-02-0...
Name: startDate, dtype: object
```

For each element in the series (i.e. for each list of dates), I want to retain the longest sublist in which all dates are consecutive. I'm struggling to approach this in a pythonic (simple/efficient) way. The only approach that I can think of is to use multiple loops: loop over the series values (the lists), and loop over each element in the list. I would then store the first date and the number of consecutive days, and use temporary values to overwrite the results if a longer sequence of consecutive days is encountered. This seems highly inefficient though. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: convert dates to ordinals and get longest increasing sub-array. I posted the answer you can try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention you are using numpy arrays of dates it makes sense to stick to numpy types instead of converting to the built-in type. I'm assuming here that your arrays have dtype 'datetime64[D]'. In that case you could do something like

```
import numpy as np

date_list = np.array(['2005-02-01', '2005-02-02', '2005-02-03',
       '2005-02-05', '2005-02-06', '2005-02-07', '2005-02-08', '2005-02-09',
       '2005-02-11', '2005-02-12',
       '2005-02-14', '2005-02-15', '2005-02-16', '2005-02-17',
       '2005-02-19', '2005-02-20',
       '2005-02-22', '2005-02-23', '2005-02-24',
       '2005-02-25', '2005-02-26', '2005-02-27', '2005-02-28'],
      dtype='datetime64[D]')

i0max, i1max = 0, 0
i0 = 0
for i1, date in enumerate(date_list):
    if date - date_list[i0] != np.timedelta64(i1-i0, 'D'):
        if i1 - i0 > i1max - i0max:
            i0max, i1max = i0, i1
        i0 = i1

print(date_list[i0max:i1max])

# output: ['2005-02-05' '2005-02-06' '2005-02-07' '2005-02-08' '2005-02-09']
```

Here, `i0` and `i1` indicate the start and stop indeces of the current sub-array of consecutive dates, and `i0max` and `i1max` the start and stop indices of the longest sub-array found so far. The solution uses the fact that the difference between the `i`-th and zeroth entry in a list of consecutive dates is exactly `i` days.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert list to ordinals which are increasing for all consecutive dates. Which means `next_date = previous_date + 1` [read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date).

Then find the longest consecutive sub-array.

This process will take `O(n)->single loop` time which is the most efficient way to get this.

**CODE**

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_consecutive(date_list):
  # convert to ordinals
  v = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()  for d in date_list]
  consecutive = []
  run = []
  dates = []

  # get consecutive ordinal sequence 
  for i in range(1, len(v) + 1):
    run.append(v[i-1])
    dates.append(date_list[i-1])
    if i == len(v) or v[i-1] + 1 != v[i]:
      if len(consecutive) < len(run):
        consecutive = dates
      dates = []
      run = []

  return consecutive
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
date_list = ['2019-01-29', '2019-01-30', '2019-01-31','2019-02-05']
get_consecutive(date_list )
# ordinales will be -> v = [737088, 737089, 737090, 737095]
OUTPUT:
['2019-01-29', '2019-01-30', '2019-01-31']
```

Now use `get_consecutive` in `df.column.apply(get_consecutive)`it will give you all increasing date list. Or you can all function for each list if you are using some other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reduce this problem to finding consecutive days in a single list. There are a few tricks that make it more Pythonic as you ask. The following script should run as-is. I've documented how it works inline:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, date

# example input
days = [
    date(2020, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 2), date(2020, 1, 4),
    date(2020, 1, 5), date(2020, 1, 6), date(2020, 1, 8),
]

# store the longest interval and the current consecutive interval
# as we iterate through a list
longest_interval_index = current_interval_index =  0
longest_interval_length = current_interval_length = 1

# using zip here to reduce the number of indexing operations
# this will turn the days list into [(2020-01-1, 2020-01-02), (2020-01-02, 2020-01-03), ...]
# use enumerate to get the index of the current day
for i, (previous_day, current_day) in enumerate(zip(days, days[1:]), start=1):
    if current_day - previous_day == timedelta(days=+1):
        # we've found a consecutive day! increase the interval length
        current_interval_length += 1
    else:
        # nope, not a consecutive day! start from this day and start
        # counting from 1
        current_interval_index = i
        current_interval_length = 1
    if current_interval_length > longest_interval_length:
        # we broke the record! record it as the longest interval
        longest_interval_index = current_interval_index
        longest_interval_length = current_interval_length

print("Longest interval index:", longest_interval_index)
print("Longest interval: ", days[longest_interval_index:longest_interval_index + longest_interval_length])
```

It should be easy enough to turn this into a reusable function.